# Updating model value onChange in Meteor + React places cursor at the end of the string

Tags: meteor, reactjs

I am using Meteor with React. Consider this simple component below. There is a local mini-Mongo collection CommentsCollection. The component will insert a row in it when `componentWillMount` will be called. `getMeteorData` will return the first record in the collection and we'll be able to modify the title. Problem: if I place my cursor at the start of the title and start typing, after the first character update the cursor will jump to the end of the string and the rest of my typing will be placed there. How do I work around this?

```
CommentsCollection = new Meteor.Collection(null); // Local mini-mongo collection
EventTestComponent = React.createClass({
mixins   : [ReactMeteorData],
    componentWillMount(){
        CommentsCollection.insert({title:"test title", message:"some test message"});
    },
    getMeteorData(){
        return {
            comment: CommentsCollection.findOne()
        };
    },

    handleTitleChange(e){
        CommentsCollection.update({_id: this.data.comment._id}, {$set:{title: e.target.value}});
    },
    render(){
        if(this.data.comment) {
            return (
                <div>
                    <input type="text" value={this.data.comment.title} onChange={this.handleTitleChange}/>
                </div>
            );
        }else{
            return <div>Loading...</div>
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this solution right after I posted the question:

```
<input type="text"
                           defaultValue={this.data.comment.title}
                           onKeyUp={this.handleTitleChange}/>
```

So: change `value` to `defaultValue`, and `onChange` to `onKeyUp`. Works like a charm!